# How do you write an interface with a generic which is always an array?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function:

```
export function limitToApiContraints<T extends Array>(payload: T, type: IQueueTypes) {
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately the signature of the generic errors out saying:

> Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).

If I change this to :

```
export function limitToApiContraints<T extends Array<any>>(payload: T, type: IQueueTypes) {
  return foo as T;
}
```

the function signature passes structural tests but when I return `foo` as **T** it comes back as `ready: any[] | IGitHubRepoMap[]` (where T = IGitHubRepoMap[]).

How can I state that T will always be an array but preserve a discreet type is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the array property part of the definition of the generic, but instead use

```
function test<T>(payload: T[]) { ... }
```

Comment: Funny I JUST did that. But does that mean that passing the generic type as an array isn't possible?

Comment: The problem with `any[]` is that it's not what you think: it doesn't mean "an array of objects which are of the same type", it means "an array of whatever". So `[42, "Foo"]` fits that type as well.